# Chmod on files and folders not already on that bit mask

Tags: find, chmod

Is there a way to change perms only on files/folders not on those perms already?

Say, if executing `find . -type f -exec chmod 0640 {} \;` on a file that is already in 0640, skip it and don't overwrite.

I'm syncing (trough `lsyncd`) files from one to many hosts and when executing that command, ALL files are modified and so, all files are also synced. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct and fastest way is

`find . -type f ! -perm 644 -exec chmod 644 {} \;`